# i would like to substract the div child from the parent one to display the background div as background for the child

Tags: html, css, class, background, transparency

Ok i don't know if it's possible, but i would like to make a specific element transparent for a div that is not the parent onen something like this

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">i would like this background div to be transparent but I don't want it to 
     display the parent div but the background div by transparency</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if it's clear but i would like to substract the div child from the parent one to display the background div as background for the child.

Here is the site i'm working on (it's for the sidebar menu, for the clicked class) :

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="FR-fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon/favicon.png" />
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <script>
            ( function(w,d,s,l,i) {
                w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});
            var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';
            j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            }) (window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KH46994');
        </script>
    <title>Portfolio | Guillaume Walter</title>
</head>
<body onload="onload()">
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="profile">
                    <img src="img/img-site/profile-picture.png"/>
                    <h3>Guillaume Walter</h3>
                    <div class="social-networks">
                        <a href="https://github.com/Gamordstrimerr" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-github github"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin linkdn"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="links">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home" id="linkmenu1" class="clicked">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></span>
                            <span class="item">Accueil</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#aboutme" id="linkmenu2">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></span>
                            <span class="item">Présentation</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#career" id="linkmenu3">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-timeline"></i></span>
                            <span class="item">Parcours</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="linkmenu4">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-code"></i></span>
                            <span class="item">Projets</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="linkmenu5">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-book"></i></span>
                            <span class="item">Veilles</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="linkmenu6">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i></span>
                            <span class="item">Contacts</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="footer-sidebar">
                    <p>Guillaume Walter © 2023</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <section id="home" class="home">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="toggleside">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title-main">
                        <h1>GUILLAUME WALTER</h1>
                        <h2>Bienvenue sur mon portfolio</h2>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </section>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
        <section id="aboutme" class="aboutme">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>About Me</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="career" class="career">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Career</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
    <script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//======================== Menu Sidebar ========================
var linkIds = ['linkmenu1', 'linkmenu2', 'linkmenu3', 'linkmenu4', 'linkmenu5', 'linkmenu6'];
for (var i = 0; i < linkIds.length; i++) {
    var link = document.getElementById(linkIds[i]);
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!this.classList.contains('clicked')) {
            for (var j = 0; j < linkIds.length; j++) {
                var otherLink = document.getElementById(linkIds[j]);
                otherLink.classList.remove('clicked');
            }
            this.classList.add('clicked');
        }
    });
}

//======================== Body ==============================
function onload() {
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/portfolio/index.php#home"; //to modify
}
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    /*color primary*/
    --color-primary: #191d2b;
    --color-secondary: #262B40;
    --color-tertiary: #2D344D;
    --color-hover: #222639;

    /*light blue*/
    --color-light-blue1: #0D7DD3;
    --color-light-blue2: #0F89E6;
    --color-light-blue3: #1993F0;
    --color-light-blue4: #279AF1;

    /*color fix*/
    --color-white: #fff;
    --color-glow: #00ffdf;
    --color-black: #000;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: var(--color-white);
    /*background-color: var(--color-primary);*/
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

/*======================== SideBar ========================*/
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper .sidebar {
    background: var(--color-tertiary);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, var(--color-secondary) 0%, var(--color-tertiary) 100%);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15rem;
    padding: 2% 0;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .profile{
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .profile .social-networks {
    margin-top: 8%;
    height: 5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .profile .social-networks i {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--color-white);
    background-color: var(--color-light-blue1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 4%;
    margin: 2%;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .profile img{
    display: block;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 8rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.563rem 0.25rem var(--color-light-blue4);
    animation: glow 1.5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes glow{
    to {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 1rem var(--color-light-blue1);
    }
  }

.wrapper .sidebar .profile h3{
    color: var(--color-white);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin: 20% 0 1%;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li {
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 7% 10%;
    color: var(--color-white);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: var(--color-light-blue1);
    background-color: var(--color-hover);
    margin: 5% 5%;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a.clicked { <====== i would like that this div display in background the div container
    margin-left: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1.3rem 0% 0% 1.3rem;
    color: var(--color-light-blue1);
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding: 7% 10%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a.clicked::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -3.125rem;
    height: 3.125rem;
    width: 1.563rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 1.563rem;
    box-shadow: 0 -1.563rem 0 0 var(--color-primary);
    z-index: 2;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a.clicked::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    right: 0;
    top: -3.125rem;
    height: 3.125rem;
    width: 1.563rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1.563rem;
    box-shadow: 0 1.563rem 0 0 var(--color-primary);
    z-index: 2;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a.clicked:hover {
    margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}

.wrapper .sidebar ul li a .icon{
    width: 1.875rem;
    display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .footer-sidebar {
    background: var(--color-light-blue1);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

/*======================== main-header ========================*/

.wrapper .container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/bg.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.wrapper .container .title-main {
    /*border: 2px solid black;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper .home .title-main h1 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.wrapper .home .title-main h2{
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1.25rem var(--color-glow),
             0 0 1.875rem var(--color-light-blue2),
             0 0 2.5rem var(--color-light-blue4);
}

main .aboutme {
    background-color: var(--color-secondary);
}
```

I already search on google and i ask chatgpt but neither were able to give me an answer. Thank you for your precious answers, I'll try to come check it out as soon as possible.

Gamordstrimer

Comment: You could fake it by putting the same background on the child and giving the background a fixed position in relation to the viewport.

Comment: this is what i've done for now, but the problem i that the sidebar menu need to have it color and it need be different as the image one background